# ckeditor stylesheet parser in fullpage mode

Tags: ckeditor

Is it possible to use the stylesheet parser in full page mode? I can get either of these features to work, but not both. For example, the following settings result in an empty styles combo box.

```
var editor1 = CKEDITOR.replace('editor1', {
            contentsCss: ['myStyles.css'], 
            stylesSet: [], 
            fullPage: true,
            allowedContent: true
        });
```

If I comment out the "styleSet: []" line, then the combo box gets populated with the default styles, and mine don't get added. On the other hand, if I comment out "fullPage: true", then my styles get added, but I'm not in full page mode.

I'm using the latest version of ckeditor (4.4.7). Thanks for any help ...